# How to change Add Store Code to Urls from magento database

Tags: mysql, magento

I changed in my magento backend System->Configuration->Web->Url Options the field Add Store Code to Urls to Yes, now i can't see my backend because magento don't find the page i don't know why. I need to change already that, but i don't know how to find the table to do that in magento database.

thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Magento keeps configuration values in the `core_config_data`. This means that every field you can see in System Configuration is saved into table mentioned above.

So, in order to bring back the previous value for 'Add Store Code to Urls' use this SQL query:

```
UPDATE core_config_data SET value=0 WHERE path='web/url/use_store' and scope_id=0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use direct sql update with:

```
update core_config_data 
set value = 0
where path='web/url/use_store'
```

or you can also you path edit of your url like:

```
http://[your-domain-name]/index.php/admin/[your-admin-path]
```

for example:

```
http://www.localhost/index.php/admin/admin
```

you can reach to administrator in magento.